# Showing a white header stripe where the toolbar should be

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When opening various pages of the console.cloud.google  I am getting a white header stripe where toolbars should be. This issue started to occur some weeks/months ago. (See screenshot)
[image]

It seems to be a browser specific problem as I am only getting this issue when using Firefox but not with Chrome.

I am running "Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon" and "Firefox 75.0 64-Bit for Linux Mint"

Comment: Ah in fact there seems to be an Issue in Google's Tracker already: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154260224

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the specific version of the browser as you are mentioning. I would recommend you to open a bug to GCP over at their [issues page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that they can address it.

Hope you find this useful!